# probability c++ question

Tags: c++

I have to make a game of craps and towards the end, I have to do some probability.  Here is my code so far. I want it so that the loop repeats 1000 times and looks for the 'probNumb' that the user entered. I am not sure if did this right but lets say I entered the number 5. This is what I get.
"Out of 1000 times, 5 was rolled 1000 times."

So, its not counting how many times 5 was rolled. I am not allowed to use break or continue statements, only loops and if else.

```
cout << "What number do you want the probability of ?";
cin >> probNumb;

while (probCount < 1000)
{
  ranNumb= 1 + (rand() % (5 + 1));
  ranNumb2= 1 + (rand() % (5 + 1));
  ranNumbFin = ranNumb + ranNumb2;
  probCount++;

  if (ranNumbFin = probNumb)
    probNumbCount++;
}

cout << "Out of 1000 times, " << probNumb << " was rolled " 
  << probNumbCount << "times." << endl;
```

Comment: C made a huge mistake in using `=` as the assignment operator and C++ was saddled with the consequences.

Comment: @Bojan: "probably" :). but in this case it doesn't matter, he worked on it.

Comment: Yea, I know i am not suppose to post homework, but I figured that since I had all the code done, just wasn't sure why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 10):

`if (ranNumbFin = probNumb)` is either a typo or should use `==`

It's 1000 because the assignment returns the value assigned and since that's always non-zero in this case, it's always true.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks! I was getting really frustrated because I know the logic was correct but it kept on giving 1000.

Answer (score 4):

it's a typo

```
if (ranNumbFin = probNumb)
```

should be

```
if (ranNumbFin == probNumb)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your line `if (ranNumbFin = probNumb)` should be `if (ranNumbFin == probNumb)` - you're assigning, not comparing, which is causing the probNumbCount to increment every time.

Answer (score 0):

My use of C and C++ is rusty, but I believe the ranNumb and ranNumb2 are not going to behave like dice rolls.  These will just give a uniform random variate over 0 to 1.

Conceptually, for a six sided dice:

```
   u = rand();
    if(u < 1/6) ranNumb=1;
    elseif(u < 2/6) ranNumb=2;
    elseif(u < 3/5) ranNumb = 3;
```

An so on.  There is probably a better performing method.

Comment: rand() returns a integer [0-RAND_MAX)